# Delimiter within field value SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, delimiter

I have a csv file which has over 20 million rows, the delimiter is the vertical bar. The issue is that there is a text column in the file which include also vertical bars within the texts, this messes up the data and cause the column to shift to the next one when importing the csv file in the SQL Server.

The file is too big to handle, e.g. if we want to add a qualifier or change the delimiter type using even fancy text editors.

Any idea? Ideally, any general solution for issues like this? Sometimes although you are using qualifiers, there might be text fields containing qualifier-like strings, delimiters, etc..

The fields are not quoted. The rows look simply like this:

```
field1|field2|field3|field4  
1|000|some text|some text  
2|001|some text con|taining pipe|some text  
3|002|some text|some text
```

Comment: To confirm: the field containing the vertical bar: is this quoted? If not what criteria can you use to separate the case where that field contains a vertical bar from its use as a separator?

Comment: Please show us the first few rows of data.

Comment: The fields are not quoted.

Comment: Could you include an example row with the unquoted field containing the pipe? Also, how would you even manually distinguish the separator pipe and the pipe as part of the string?

Comment: A column separator that can also appear in the columns themselves, shouldn't be used as a column separator. That speaks for itself.

Comment: I have edited my original post, please see sample dummy data. I have noticed the error after uploading the csv file to the database. I sorted (asc/desc) the numerical column after the column containing the texts and I noticed that part of the text "jumbed" to the next column. I hope this clarifies.

Comment: In your example, where is the pipe within a field? All rows contain exactly 3 pipes so it does not provide an example to your problem.

Comment: The only 100% guaranteed solution would be to regenerate the file and this time handle the delimiter/qualifiers in advance. Is this feasible? If not you have some data processing to do (do you have Linux/Unix available?) and you might loose some of the records

Comment: Daniel: I edited the dummy data, can't show the real data. So for example the second row field3 has a pipe within the text.

Comment: Dudu: can not really regenerate the data. Unfortunately I don't have Linux or Unix in use.

Comment: Can you install cygwin or anything else that supports `awk`? https://www.cygwin.com/

Comment: Never used before but I can install it, then will check how to use it. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Please install and then follow my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With access to bash (Linux/Unix/Cygwin etc.)

---

In order to estimate the severity of the issue, check the number of records with 4 fields and with other numbers of fields .

```
awk -F'|' '{rec[NF==4?"NF=4":"NF!=4"]++}END{for(nf in rec){print nf,rec[nf]}}' MyFile.csv
```

Generate a file with the good records and load it.

```
awk -F'|' 'NF==4{print}' MyFile.csv > MyFile_good.csv
```

Generate a file with the bad records and check if you can fix it manually or some other way (If you identify patterns)

```
awk -F'|' 'NF!=4{print}' MyFile.csv > MyFile_bad.csv
```

---

#### Support for qualifiers

```
"1"|"000"|"some text"|"some text"  
"2"|"001"|"some text con|taining pipe"|"some text"  
"3"|"002"|"some text"|"some text"
```

---

Instead of defining a separator (`awk -F'|'`) we are now defining how a qualified field looks like (`FPAT="\"[^\"]*\""`)

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t";FPAT="\"[^\"]*\""}{rec[NF==4?"NF=4":"NF!=4"]++}END{for(nf in rec){print nf,rec[nf]}}' MyFile.csv
```

Comment: Excellent Dudu! Powerful tool, efficient scripts. Managed to isolate those messy records, fixed them manually (not much luckily) and merged them back with the "good" records. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Great to hear :-) It would be more effecient to do everything in one pass but I preffered to keep it simple. I'll add a one liner later.

Comment: One question: how about if I have the same set of data but a qualifier (")is used for all all the fileds? How can it be declared in the same scripts above?

Comment: Are there separators ('|') within the qualifiers?

Comment: Hi Dudu, now accepted :) Sorry not very familiar with all the features here yet.

Comment: About your question, that needs to be found out as the file has millions of rows.

Comment: Basically it should not be but there is a possibility that a separator can be within the qualifier for a few rows for one text field.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Does this work regardless of the delimiter type? Say I have semicolon (;) delimiter instead of pipe (|).

Comment: You should replace It in the FPAT

Comment: Thanks for the prompt help, mcuh appreciated.

Comment: I was mistaken about the separator, no need to define it

Answer (score 1):

You can import entire row into NVARCHAR(MAX) column and fix or parse by T-SQL

```
CREATE TABLE MyCSV (
    csv NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL      -- VARCHAR(MAX) NULL
)
GO

BULK INSERT   MyCSV 
FROM 'data_file' 
WITH (
    DATAFILETYPE =   'widechar' --'char' 
    ,FIELDTERMINATOR = '\r\n'
)
-- OR WITH (FORMATFILE='C:\t_floatformat-c-xml.xml'); 
GO

/*
INSERT INTO MyCSV 
VALUES 
    ('1|000|some text|some text')
    ,('2|001|some text con|taining pipe|some text')
    ,('3|002|some text|some text')
*/

ALTER TABLE MyCSV 
    ADD RowID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
GO
```

For parsng you can use this function:

```
-- SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Split2Column] (N'1|000|some text|some text', N'|')
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split2Column] (  
    @String NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @SepColumn NCHAR(1)
)
RETURNS @Columns TABLE (
     [1] NVARCHAR(MAX)
    ,[2] NVARCHAR(MAX)
    ,[3] NVARCHAR(MAX)
    ,[4] NVARCHAR(MAX)
    ,[5] NVARCHAR(MAX)
    ,[6] NVARCHAR(MAX)
    ,[7] NVARCHAR(MAX)
    ,[8] NVARCHAR(MAX)
    ,[9] NVARCHAR(MAX)
    ,[10] NVARCHAR(MAX)
)

AS
BEGIN

    ;WITH columns (cn, n1, n2 ) AS ( 
    SELECT CAST(1 as int) as cn, CAST(0 as bigint) as n1, CHARINDEX(@SepColumn, @String + @SepColumn) as n2
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT cn + 1, n2 as n1, CHARINDEX(@SepColumn, @String + @SepColumn, n2 + 1) as n2
    FROM columns
    WHERE n2 < LEN(@String)
    )

    INSERT INTO @Columns
    SELECT [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10]
    FROM 
        (
        SELECT cn,
            SUBSTRING(@String, n1 + 1, n2 - n1 - 1) as val
        FROM columns) parsed
    PIVOT (
            MIN(val) FOR cn IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10]) 
        ) pvt
        OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);

    RETURN;
END
GO
```

And here result:

```
SELECT MyCSV.RowID
    ,[Split2Column].*
FROM MyCSV
    CROSS APPLY [dbo].[Split2Column] (MyCSV.csv, N'|')
--WHERE [Split2Column].[5] IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY MyCSV.RowID

RowID   1   2   3               4               5           6       7       8       9       10
1       1   000 some text       some text       NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
2       2   001 some text con   taining pipe    some text   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
3       3   002 some text       some text       NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Comment: Thanks AlexK for your time and for your help.